# Processing a row externally that fired a trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm working on a PostgreSQL 9.3-database on an Ubuntu 14 server.

I try to write a trigger-function (AFTER EACH ROW) that launches an external process that needs to access the row that fired that trigger.

**My problem**:
Even tough I can run queries on the table including the new row *inside* the trigger, the *external* process does not see it (while the trigger function is still running).

Is there a way to manage that?

---

I thought about starting some kind of asynchronous function call to give the trigger some time to terminate first, but that's of course *really* ugly.

Also I read about `notifiers` and `listeners`, but that would require some refactoring of my existing code and also some additional listener, which I tried to prevent with my trigger. (I'm also afraid of new problems which may occur on this road.)

Any more thoughts?

Robin

Comment: No, that won't be possible. When the trigger is fired, the transaction has not been committed yet, so any external application won't see the new data. The only solution I can see is a way where you _pass_ the necessary information from the row to the external process (e.g. through JSON)

Comment: Probably something like dirty read isolation level could helps but i am not sure that it is a good idea...

Comment: @Abelisto: Postgres does not support read uncommitted